# Is "scholaris opus, scholaris vox" a correct translation of "student work, student voice"?

Tags: idiom, motto

Some students of mine are creating a school publication featuring student work, and the proposed subtitle of their publication is:

> Scholaris Opus, Scholaris Vox

The intended meaning is "student work, student voice" or "scholar" in place of "student."  The content of the publication will be be broad and include essays, poetry, mathematics, science, photography, and visual art.  Online dictionaries seem to translate it to the intended meaning, but I just wanted to make sure the Latin is correct.

Comment: Welcome!  If you'd like, it may be worth including more context to clarify the type of "work" that the students are attempting to convey in the subtitle.  Work can obviously refer to many things, from physical labor to the step-by-step process for solving a problem ("show your work!") to artistic masterpieces, and this may impact the Latin translation.

Comment: _Scholaris_ [actually means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dscholaris) _Of or belonging to a school_. If you intend to mean specifically _student_, then _discipulorum opus, discipulorum vox_ may be a better title. _Discipulorum_ means _of the students_. I'm not sure if _student_ in English is working as an adjective? Because in Latin I don't think a singular noun fits too well here.

Comment: Thanks @Nathaniel, I've updated the question.  Rafael, I like scholaris even more now!  "Scholaris" should be a noun acting as an adjective here, as it is describing the work and the voice.

Comment: I think it is actually an adjective ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As point out in the comments, *scholaris* is an adjective meaning "belonging to a school" or "of school".
If you say *opus scholare, vox scholaris*, it means "work of school, voice of school".
To me that sounds essentially opposite of what you want to say, so I would not suggest it.
Notice in my example above that *opus* is a neuter and therefore the adjective is in the form *scholare*.

To reach the correct tone, I strongly suggest that you pick some Latin dictionary (you can find suggestions [in this other question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79)) and find the words you wish to use.
We can then help you use them.

Let me give you some suggestions (see more detailed translations and more suggestions in a dictionary):

- Work might be *labor* (physical work), *opus* (a piece of work), *facta* (made things), *acta* (done things) or *scripta* (written things).
- A student might be *studens*, *studiosus* or *discipulus*.
- A voice might be *vox* or *dicta* (said things).

If you want to use participles, just look up the verbs that are relevant (study, do, say, write, or something) and we'll figure out suitable forms for them.
For example, *studens* comes from the verb *studere* (or *studeo* in some dictionaries), which means much more than studying.

My best guess now is *scripta studentium, dicta studentium* "things written by students, things said by students".
I'm happy to give a better suggestion if you can comment on the tone of these words and perhaps suggest better ones (see a dictionary for both).

Comment: +1, but some comments: 1) I think a better (not perfect) analogy is acta -> done things // facta -> made things, 2) [studeo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dstudeo) does mean only tangentially to study, more properly to pay attention, take pains, be diligent 3) you may want to put **scholare** in bold: that's one important thing that wasn't mentioned in the previous comments

Comment: @Rafael, thanks! I updated it. 1) *Acta* is indeed a good choice to list here. 2) *Studere* means many things indeed, but the participle *studens* seems to have a slightly narrower connotation. It is listed separately in some dictionaries. I find it important that the Jed (the OP) looks at dictionary entries to see more details that should not be listed here. 3) I have a separate sentence about having *scholare* instead of *scholaris*. That is not the key point of my answer, though, so I prefer not to bold it.